# Fetch as Google does it follow AJAX calls

Tags: ajax

I have SPA application that I'd like to test with Fetch as Google webmasters tools feature. 
If I select fetch and render my SPA is rendered correctly with images, css and javascript interpreted correctly. I also checked at my backend that AJAX calls are executed correctly I see that in my apache2 server log. 
Unfortunately the screen shot presented by Fetch as Google feature doesn't contain data returned by my AJAX calls. There are blank spaces where AJAX responses should be placed. 
May I assume that Fetch as Google feature doesn't wait for all AJAX responses and renders screen shot before that, or should I assume that Fetch as Google will not get my AJAX responses?

I get 'Complete' status from Fetch as Google, which leads me to conclusion that maybe everything is ok?

What do you guys think?

Thanks,
Tomasz Scislo

Comment: Did you follow https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that Google Webmaster Tools doesn't accept AJAX calls that requires preflight OPTIONS requests. If you get rid of those calls everything works as expected.

Comment: I know this is a long time ago, but do you remember how you figured this out?  I'm trying to debug an AJAX issue with Fetch as Google and not finding a lot of resources

Answer (score 0):

YES, it does follow AJAX and NO, it would't wait infinitely until it receives all the replies. I didn't come across a specific timeout value for the Crawler Bot to wait for AJAX and rendering completion, though I came across mentions from guys experimenting with SetTimeout (and checking the output of Fetch as Google) - it seems a second or two is tops.